# express get all values as strings from angular POST request

Tags: angularjs, express

I have a following simple code that send a POST request to a server with express:

```
$http.post('/blah', {
    boolean: true,
    stringBoolean: 'true',
    number: 213,
    stringNubmer: '44444444',
    string: 'adssd',
    arrayNumber: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    arrayBoolean: [true, false, "true", "false"],
});
```

and this lines on server side:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.post('/blah', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

the output in console after client send request(tested on chrome and firefox)  will be with all values as string:

```
{ boolean: 'true',
  stringBoolean: 'true',
  number: '213',
  stringNubmer: '44444444',
  string: 'adssd',
  arrayNumber: [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ],
  arrayBoolean: [ 'true', 'false', 'true', 'false' ] }
```

Then I use Postman to send same data structure to server:

{
    "boolean": true,
    "stringBoolean": "true",
    "number": 213,
    "stringNubmer": "44444444",
    "string": "adssd",
    "arrayNumber": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "arrayBoolean": [true, false, "true", "false"]
}

but this time I have numbers and booleans in console:

{ boolean: true,
  stringBoolean: 'true',
  number: 213,
  stringNubmer: '44444444',
  string: 'adssd',
  arrayNumber: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
  arrayBoolean: [ true, false, 'true', 'false' ] }

Seems like angular doing some conventions behind the curtains. How can I avoid that and get correct values types send to server?

UPDATE: 
In chome console I can see request body in raw format wich look like this:

```
boolean=true&stringBoolean=true&number=213&stringNubmer=44444444&string=adssd&arrayNumber%5B0%5D=1&arrayNumber%5B1%5D=2&arrayNumber%5B2%5D=3&arrayNumber%5B3%5D=4&arrayBoolean%5B0%5D=true&arrayBoolean%5B1%5D=false&arrayBoolean%5B2%5D=true&arrayBoolean%5B3%5D=false
```

which mean each value will always be string and I have to manually convert it on server side to appropriate types. Is this questing right? What are the good practices here?

Answer (score 1):

it is using `JSON.stringify()` internally. use `JSON.parse()`